# How can I return a value from a custom class to use later?

Tags: python, class, time

I've written a class in Python:

```
class TimeError(Exception):
"""A custom exception used to report errors in use of Timer Class""" 
class simulation_timer: 
    def __init__(self):
        self._simulation_start_time = None
        self._simulation_stop_time = None

    def start(self):
        """start a new timer"""
        if self._simulation_start_time is not None:    # attribute
            raise TimeError(f"Timer is running.\n Use .stop() to stop it")

        self._simulation_start_time = time.perf_counter()  
    def stop(self):
        """stop the time and report the elsaped time"""
        if self._simulation_start_time is None:
            raise TimeError(f"Timer is not running.\n Use .start() to start it.")

        self._simulation_stop_time = time.perf_counter()
        elapsed_simulation_time = self._simulation_stop_time - self._simulation_start_time  
    
        self._simulation_start_time = None
        print(f"Elapsed time: {elapsed_simulation_time:0.4f} seconds")
```

Which allows me to measure the execution time of certain parts of my code. The class only prints the value of time. I now need it to `return` a value so I can add up the measured execution times of different parts of the scrip by writing them into a `list` and then summing the list or something.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, your class `TimeError` has an indentation error and requires minimally a `pass` statement. Second, by convention ([PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)), your class `simulation_timer` is better named `SimulationTimer`.

The simplest approach is to include an additional property, `accumulated_elpased_time`, initialized to `0.0`. The `stop` method simply adds to this property the current `elapsed_simulation_time`. A new method, `get_accululated_time` is implemented to retrieve this property value:

```
import time

class TimeError(Exception):
    """A custom exception used to report errors in use of Timer Class"""
    pass


class SimulationTimer:
    def __init__(self):
        self._simulation_start_time = None
        self._simulation_stop_time = None
        self.accumulated_elpased_time = 0.0

    def start(self):
        """start a new timer"""
        if self._simulation_start_time is not None:    # attribute
            raise TimeError(f"Timer is running.\n Use .stop() to stop it")
        self._simulation_start_time = time.perf_counter()

    def stop(self):
        """stop the time and report the elsaped time"""
        if self._simulation_start_time is None:
            raise TimeError(f"Timer is not running.\n Use .start() to start it.")

        self._simulation_stop_time = time.perf_counter()
        elapsed_simulation_time = self._simulation_stop_time - self._simulation_start_time
        self.accumulated_elpased_time += elapsed_simulation_time

        self._simulation_start_time = None
        print(f"Elapsed time: {elapsed_simulation_time:0.4f} seconds")

    def get_accumulated_time(self):
        """get accumulated elsaped time"""
        return self.accumulated_elpased_time


simulation_timer = SimulationTimer()
simulation_timer.start()
time.sleep(3)
simulation_timer.stop()
simulation_timer.start()
time.sleep(2)
simulation_timer.stop()
print(f"Accumulated time: {simulation_timer.get_accumulated_time():0.4f} seconds")
```

Prints:

```
Elapsed time: 2.9992 seconds
Elapsed time: 1.9997 seconds
Accumulated time: 4.9989 seconds
```